# ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper: incorrect behaviour when used with Bindings.or

Tags: java, javafx, property-binding

I encountered a very strange behavior when binding two `ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper` objects using a `Binding.or`. Namely, the result is not correct (still false) when I do `b1.set(true)` on the first argument.

Here's a simple unit test (that fails):

```
@Test
public void testReadOnlyBooleanWrapper() {
    // Fails!!!
    testOr(new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false), new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false));
}

public void testOr(BooleanProperty b1, BooleanProperty b2) {
    BooleanExpression or = b1.or(b2);

    assertEquals(or.get(), b1.get() || b2.get());
    b1.set(true);
    assertEquals(or.get(), b1.get() || b2.get());
    b1.set(false);
    assertEquals(or.get(), b1.get() || b2.get());
}
```

Note that the same test with `SimpleBooleanProperties` works fine:

```
@Test
public void testSimpleBooleanProperty() {
    // Passes
    testOr(new SimpleBooleanProperty(false), new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
}
```

I'm probably missing some point here and misusing the properties, because I can't imagine such a bug in the implementation! :)

Thanks for any ideas how to explain it!

UPDATE:

Your answers and comments have put me on the right track :) I don't have the solution yet, but I've noticed that if I bind the `or` to `ReadOnlyProperties` (supposed to be exposed) and not to the wrappers themselves, then the test passes:

```
@Test
public void testOrReadOnly() {
    ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper b1 = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false);
    ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper b2 = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false);

    BooleanExpression or = b1.getReadOnlyProperty().or(b2.getReadOnlyProperty());

    System.out.println("Condition " + or.get());
    assertEquals(or.get(), b1.get() || b2.get());
    b1.set(true);
    System.out.println("Condition " + or.get());
    assertEquals(or.get(), b1.get() || b2.get());
    b1.set(false);
    System.out.println("Condition " + or.get());
    assertEquals(or.get(), b1.get() || b2.get());
}
```

Which makes me think that the synchronization between the internal read- and write-able property and the read-only one, is somehow broken (?)

From the Docs about `ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper`:

> This class provides a convenient class to define read-only properties. It creates two properties that are **synchronized**. One property is read-only and can be passed to external users. The other property is read- and writable and should be used internally only.

Comment: @assylias It's a read only *wrapper*: i.e. it is a fully-writable property that wraps a `ReadOnlyProperty`. This API is designed for representing values that can only be changed from the bean containing them, but which can expose a `ReadOnlyProperty` as public API for observing externally.

Comment: This is a "wrapper": you can still use it as a normal property, but can expose a read-only version to clients. According to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug (imo).

What is happening is that the implementation of the `or` binding implements a shortcircuit for the "or" (this is in [Bindings.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/base/src/main/java/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.java)):

```
    @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        final BooleanOrBinding binding = ref.get();
        if (binding == null) {
            observable.removeListener(this);
        } else {
            // short circuit invalidation. This BooleanBinding becomes
            // only invalid if the first operator changes or the
            // first parameter is false.
            if ((binding.op1.equals(observable) || (binding.isValid() && !binding.op1.get()))) {
                binding.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
```

The listener implementing this is added to each of the operands in the `or`: however, `ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper` delegates the listener to its `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty` (from [ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/base/src/main/java/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java)):

```
@Override
public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
    getReadOnlyProperty().addListener(listener);
}
```

Thus in the shortcircuit implementation, `binding.op1.equals(observable)` is `false` (because one is the `ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper`, and the other is its `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty`). So the logic here is (incorrectly) assuming the second operator has changed. Since the first operator has the value `true`, the conclusion of the implementation is that the evaluation of the `or` cannot have changed, so no invalidation is fired. Hence your `or` doesn't get re-evaluated.

The workaround, as you have discovered, is to use the wrapped `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty` in computing the binding. I recommend you report this bug.

Comment: This is quite a complete explanation, thanks for getting to the bottom of it! P.S. Do you think I need to submit a bug report?

Comment: Yes, I think a bug report is in order. Note the same thing happens with `and` when changing `true & true` to `false & true`. I think the best fix is replacing `binding.op1.equals(observable)` with `(! binding.op2.equals(observable))`.